# Adding items from a Map to a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, maps, jcombobox

sorry I don't have any code but just need some recommendation, is there a way I can add items from a Map to a JComboBox, to also dynamically change when new are items added and deleted?

Thanks.

Comment: Map has keys and values. What you want to insert into your combobox? Some maps have no order, so each time when you transfer elements from map to combobox, you'll get a different element order. Dynamic synchronization between `Map` and combobox is not possible, because standard map implementations (like `HashMap` or `HashTable`) trigger no events on change.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the clarification! The values of the HashMap onto the JComboBox

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but just for context If I have an add button to add items to this hashmap, can I trigger this add button to redraw the jComboBox according to the new HashMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your combobox you can use something like this.

```
// due to order problem, transfer of elements from map to combo box have sence 
// for ordered maps, like LinkedHashMap or TreeMap
Map<String, String> strMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// fill map...
JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
// some code...
// now update the combo box content
combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(strMap.values().toArray(new String[0])));
```

More assitance could be possible, when you post you code in form of [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: When I use the DefaultComboBoxModel, does it update Dynamicallly?

Comment: Only when you execute the last line each time when your map is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use values of the hashmap using ...

```
yourMap.values().forEach((value)-> {
       // Do whatever your want with each value. 
    });
```

Comment: Whenever you have changes in your map, you can call this directly to change.